# Google Map Places Autocomplete error 429 in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I am facing 429 error code in google map places api while every thing is ok.I have billing account and also restricted my api but i get the following error.

{ "error": { "code": 429, "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).", "errors": [ "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).", "domain": "global", "reason": "rateLimitExceeded", "debugInfo": "detail: "[ORIGINAL ERROR] generic::resource_exhausted: com.google.api.server.core.Fault: ImmutableErrorDefinition{base=TOO_MANY_REQUESTS, category=QUOTA_ERROR, cause=null, debugInfo=null, domain=usageLimits, extendedHelp=null, httpHeaders={}, httpStatus=tooManyRequests, internalReason=Reason{arguments={}, cause=null, code=canonicalResourceExhaustedFromBackend, createdByBackend=false, debugMessage=null, errorProtoCode=null, errorProtoDomain=null, filteredMessage=null, location=null, message=null, unnamedArguments=[]}, location=null, message=Rate Limit Exceeded, reason=rateLimitExceeded, rpcCode=429} Rate Limit Exceeded"\n" ], "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED" }

```
08-02 16:37:37.188 194-3188/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [InputMethod](this:0xb39bdc00,id:67,api:1,p:1263,c:194) allocateBuffers: slot 0 without buffer is not FREE
08-02 16:37:37.200 1580-3279/? E/art: invalid stream - problem with parameter iterator in /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk:classes3.dex for method void com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(int)
08-02 16:37:37.285 1580-3279/? E/art: invalid stream - problem with parameter iterator in /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk:classes3.dex for method void com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(int)
08-02 16:37:37.925 1580-3279/? E/Volley: [168] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 429 for https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/autocompleteWidget?key=AIzaSyCyJ-q6antCvgUAeYmix_5caFVwHhPiUgE
08-02 16:37:37.949 1580-6776/? E/ErrorUtils: Received generic error from server: 429
08-02 16:37:37.965 1580-6776/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=65, operation=AutocompleteWidgetQuota [CONTEXT service_id=259 ]
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}]
        at bjnt.a(:com.google.android.gms@202614017@20.26.14 (040306-320008519):2)
        at bjnf.a(:com.google.android.gms@202614017@20.26.14 (040306-320008519):4)
        at zwo.run(:com.google.android.gms@202614017@20.26.14 (040306-320008519):9)
        at bmvl.run(:com.google.android.gms@202614017@20.26.14 (040306-320008519):2)
        at skp.b(:com.google.android.gms@202614017@20.26.14 (040306-320008519):12)
        at skp.run(:com.google.android.gms@202614017@20.26.14 (040306-320008519):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at sql.run(:com.google.android.gms@202614017@20.26.14 (040306-320008519):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-02 16:37:37.996 6264-6264/? E/Places: Autocomplete widget closing due to ERROR

08-02 16:37:39.505 6264-6264/? E/Places: Unknown PlaceAutocompleteAdapter state change.
08-02 16:37:39.556 1580-8916/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=65, operation=AutocompleteWidgetQuota [CONTEXT service_id=259 ]
```

My build.gradle have the following dependencies

````
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.12.1'
    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    implementation 'com.splunk.mint:mint:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
    implementation group: 'com.pubnub', name: 'pubnub-gson', version: '4.6.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.1+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'```  

What may be a cause of error?
````

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly mentions "Quota Exhausted" so you might need to upgrade your plan in google console.

Comment: You had a lot of requests... check your config to verify the sessiontoken attribute.  It is a random string which identifies an autocomplete session for billing purposes. If this parameter is omitted from an autocomplete request, the request is billed independently.  You have more information about this in the official page https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update your implementation as shown here:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Places SDK for Android has been deprecated. Just enable Places API and follow the Migration Guide.